# edit model using selectbox nested_form gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nested-forms, nested-attributes

I have a nested form gem issue and can't figure it out for days.

When "edit" model, why my selectbox not filled with current value from database?

**my "customize" view :**

```
<%= nested_form_for @order_detail, :url => create_customize_cart_path do |f| %>
    # some field here
    <%= f.fields_for :order_customs do |builder| %>
      <%= render "order_customs_form", :f => builder %>
    <% end %>
    <%= f.link_to_add "Add Order Customize", :order_customs %>
    <%= f.submit %>  
<%end%>
```

**my partial view (as nested) :**

```
<%= f.label :pressed_position, "Position" %>
<%= f.select :pressed_position, options_for_select(PRESSED_POSITION), {:include_blank => '-- Select Position --'} %>
<%= f.link_to_remove "Remove Customize" %>
```

**PRESSED POSITION as CONSTANT**
and data store "string" value

```
PRESSED_POSITION = [
  ["Top", "top"],
  ["Center","center"],
  ["Bottom","bottom"],
  ["Right", "right"],
  ["Left", "left"],
  ["Top Left", "top left"],
  ["Top Center", "top center"],
  ["Top Right", "top right"],
  ["Center Left", "center left"],
  ["Center Center", "center center"],
  ["Center Right", "center right"],
  ["Bottom Left", "bottom left"],
  ["Bottom Center", "bottom center"],
  ["Bottom Right", "bottom right"]
]
```

For textfield it works (filled with current data), but if i using selectbox it doesn't

**in my controller :**

```
def customize
  @order_detail = OrderDetail.find_by_id(decrypting_id(params[:id])) rescue nil
  if @order_detail.present?
    if (current_user == @order_detail.order.user || temporary_user == @order_detail.order.temp_user_id) && @order_detail.order.order_status_id == 1 
      1.times{@order_detail.order_customs}
    else
      # else going here
    end
  else
    # else going here
  end    
end
```

Can You guys tell me what should I do to solve this problem?
Realy appreciate it, thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't test it right now, but I would do it like this:

**your view**  **EDITED**

```
<%= nested_form_for @order_detail, :url => create_customize_cart_path do |f| %>
    # some field here
  <% @order_detail.order_customs.each do |order_custom| %>
    <%= f.fields_for :order_customs, order_custom do |builder| %>
      <%= render "order_customs_form", :f => builder, :order_custom => order_custom %>
    <% end %> 
  <% end %>
  <%= f.link_to_add "Add Order Customize", :order_customs %>
  <%= f.submit %>  
<%end%>
```

We have to pass the `order_custom` object to the partial

**The partial**

```
<%= f.label :pressed_position, "Position" %>
<%= f.select :pressed_position, options_for_select(PRESSED_POSITION, PRESSED_POSITION.index{|element| element.last==order_custom.pressed_position), {:include_blank => '-- Select Position --'} %>
<%= f.link_to_remove "Remove Customize" %>
```

This line

```
PRESSED_POSITION.index{|element| element.last==order_custom.pressed_position)
```

will return the index of the `PRESSED_POSITION` array where the last element is equal to the `pressed_position` attribute of the object `order_custom`.

I hope it helps :)

Comment: sory for late respond. I already tried your code, but throw `undefined local variable or method 'order_custom' for #<#<Class:0xb55a09c8>:0xb411533c>`. Your code trying to passing order_custom to partial view then get its index, right? But I can't produce nested form's current index. Hot to do that? Realy realy thanks to You who give Your effort into this

Comment: If I'm not wrong I have a project with this same need, I gonna look at it and come back to you.

Comment: Hey, you give me a right way :D. Related with `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15777038/getting-undefined-method-values-at-for-nilnilclass-using-nested-form-for`, i add a condition if order_customs is nil and modify a little on partial view since PRESSED_POSITION just a string value so become `PRESSED_POSITION[PRESSED_POSITION.index{|element| element.last==order_custom.pressed_position)}]`. But there is a bug, If we "add order custom" the pressed position's selectbox on last nested-form filled with `@order_detail.order_customs.last`. I will edit the answer too if I already fixed it :D