# How to set the "selected" choice in the selection box for an associated model?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model-associations

I have a Product model with many Versions:

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :name, :versions_attributes
  has_many :versions
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :versions, allow_destroy: true
end

class Version < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :available_q, :kind, :product_id
  belongs_to :product
end
```

I would like to present the `available_q` attribute to the (admin) user as a select box with the  choices of "Yes" or "No", and of course I would like the to have the select box show whatever is currently in the version database for this version, but can't seem to get it to do that. Here is the portion of the view code for the product form involving the select box for the associated model:

```
<%= form_for(@product) do |f| %>
…
<%= f.fields_for :versions do |version| %>
<%= version.select :available_q, options_for_select([['Yes', 't'],['No', 'f']], version.object.available_q) %><br />
…
<% end %>
…
```

Everything works well except that the current select box always shows yes even after updating the database with a 'No'. It's likely that I have forgotten to do something very simple, but would very much appreciate any help on this.

Comment: what is the datatype of available_q and what are the legal values for that attribute?

Answer (score 0):

```
<%= version.select :available_q, options_for_select([['Yes', 't'],['No', 'f']], version.object.available_q == 't' ? 0 : 1) %>
```

You can try the solution above. The second parameter of options_for_select isn't the value to be shown, but the index of the value on the collection array `[['Yes', 't'],['No', 'f']]`.

Comment: André, thanks for taking the time to respond to my question. `available_q` is a boolean, with values `'t'` or `'f'`. Your suggestion of using the index to set the selected item doesn't seem to work in this case (perhaps because it is in a `f.fields_for` tag?) For instance, when I tried putting simply `1` (or even `'1'`) as the second argument in the `options_for_select` function, it still didn't select "No" in the select box on reload. If you have any further thoughts on this issue, I would be glad to hear them.

Comment: hey @user2884072 actually I just realize that I've messed up the variable 'version', I thought it was an object of the model Version.
Please check this answer I gave http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19242056/edit-model-using-selectbox-nested-form-gem/19246814#19246814 which I think might help you. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

I have found a work-around: the difficulty I was having seems to have to do with using `:available_q` which has `boolean` data type. When I change it to `string` type, the problem goes away!